# How to generate pdf from html in node js

Tags: node.js, jspdf

I am using jspdf package for generating PDF. I was trying to use .html function but it is giving below error
"Error parsing CSS component value, unexpected EOF","stack":"SyntaxError: Error parsing CSS component value, unexpected EOF\n    at Parser.parseComponentValue"

Environment:
Docker Image: Ubuntu-16
Node: 10.14.0

Comment: If there's a `node` tag, I assume you host the page yourself. You can use puppeteer once server starts: https://pptr.dev/

Comment: With puppeteer i am getting this error "Failed to launch chrome! spawn /app-root/src/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686378/chrome-linux/chrome". Also followed troubleshooting guidelines mentioned here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md but no luck